# Sidekiq 3.3.0 is splitting processes automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, batch-processing, sidekiq

After an upgrade to **Sidekiq 3.3.0** it started to automatically **split processes** (workers) and run them in **batches** with a few hours difference in start time. Previously it had only **one process**. This looks like they added some new undocumented configuration. That's a big deal because instead of **N** DB connections per 1 process, you will nave now **M*N** connections. And in my case **M=5**, and that **blows the memory** completely. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

**Edit**

my `sidekiq.yml`:

```
:concurrency: 10
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
```

Comment: Even i am using the same version,But didnt came through this kind of issue.Are you using sidekiq.yml configuration file?.IF yes then please show that too

Comment: @Milind I edited and added the config file.

Answer (score 0):

K. There was no problem with Sidekiq 3.3.0 but with the start/stop script in /etc/init.d. Since it looked for v2 to kill it, and it didn't, so it continued to start new sidekiq processes. :) Hopefully that will help to someone too.